# Подскажите как подключиться к серверу по WebRTC если получил данные hostname, port, roomid, peerid, displayname

Tags: ios, swift

Перерыл кучу информации по WebRTC на ios, либо я не опытный просто, либо ничего нет, вся суть в том что я сканирую qr-code, декодирую данные и получаю hostname, port, roomid, peerid, displayname, после этого мне нужно подключиться к трансляции и демонстрировать экран телефона, подскажите пожалуйста как подключиться?